# Water molecule formed by at least one tritium atom

Tags: nuclear-physics, water, radiation, isotopes

If a water molecule is made up of at least one tritium atom, when the tritium atom(s) decay radioactively, what happens to that water molecule? Does it bond to one or two Helium atoms? Is there any chemical or nuclear equation that defines this process?

Comment: See  :  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61759/what-are-the-decay-products-of-hto      and     https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/what-does-hto-decay-into

Comment: The energy of the decay is much greater than the original chemical bonding energy. And the He-3 has no desire to be part of a water molecule.